# C# class libraries and console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this class library I created. And I am running into the issue of getting the library to work with a console application. This is just a basic assignment I'm working on but I do not know where I am going wrong. Here are my files:

Class Library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test2
{
    public class Test
    {
       public static string GetData(String prompt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }
   public static int GetInt()
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(GetData("Enter an interger"));
    }
    public static void put(String output)

    {
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
    public static void put(String output, String heading)
    {
        put(heading + '\n' + output);
    }
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = GetInt();
        int y = GetInt();
        if (x > 0 && y > 0) put(String.Format("Sum:{0}", x + y));
     }
   }
}
```

Console Application:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Test2;

  namespace ConsoleApp1
   {
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
         Test myTest = new Test();
        Test.GetData(prompt);
          }
      }
  }
```

My main issue I guess I have is calling the methods to run in the console application. No matter how much reading I do I can't seem to know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Now what is the issue to this?

Comment: my main issue is trying to get my methods I made in my class library to initiate in my console application.

Answer (score 4):

1. You don't need a Main method in your class library. The Main method in your console application is the entry point to your application.
2. If the functionality in the Main method you've defined in your class library is what you're trying to achieve for the overall application then consider moving that functionality into the Main method in your console application.
3. You've made the methods in your class library static so you don't need to instantiate an object of type Test

So my solution for you would be to have this in your Main method of your console application:

```
int x = Test.GetInt();
int y = Test.GetInt();
if (x > 0 && y > 0) Test.put(String.Format("Sum:{0}", x + y));          
Console.Read();
```

I would suggest reading up on Static Classes and Static Class members here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

When deciding to make a Static class I always come back to this quote from the above link:

> A static class can be used as a convenient container for sets of
>   methods that just operate on input parameters and do not have to get
>   or set any internal instance fields.

I would also consider changing the name of your Test class. Even in small test applications like this I find it is useful to use well defined names with meaning. It's good practice so that you will do it automatically in larger applications.

Finally, good luck with all your learning!